# .NET find paper tray size

Tags: .net, printing

Is there a way to find all print trays on a printer and get their paper sizes e.g.

```
Tray1 = A4
Tray2 = A3
Tray3 = Letter
```

I can see a way to get the Trays using something like this but it doesn't seem to have the paper size information.

```
using (System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument())
{
    foreach (System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSource paperSource in doc.PrinterSettings.PaperSources)
    {
        string trayName = paperSource.SourceName;
    }
}
```

What I am wanting to do is select the best Tray for the print job by default.

Comment: Is it web application or WPF ?

Comment: Just thinking.. if you are only looking for the best tray for the print job, why not just use the largest tray and specify the paper size??

Comment: @opatachibueze I'm not sure what you mean. If I have an A4 document I want to print to a tray with A4 paper already in it. If its an A3 doc print to an A3 tray.

Comment: Ok, did you take a look at the two links? The DeviceCapabilities API function should be able to solve your problem. You can also take a look at this link: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=3687&lngWId=10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can get the printer properties which includes the paper bins (trays) for the printer using windows api:
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb258176(v=office.12).aspx
   http://www.thedbcommunity.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=218&Itemid=56
2. You could use the IPaper class in ArcObjects SDK 10 Microsoft.NET Framework (I am not quite sure about how this works)
   http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002wn000000

Edit: Just took an in depth look on one of the links I gave you, this should be the answer you're looking for:

```
// Get Printer Tray Codes for Word Printing using DeviceCapabilities
// By: BB
//
// Inputs:1)strTrayName - Name of the tray to search for, ie "Tray 1", "Tray 2", "Manual"

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the printer code for the specified tray, based on the current printer for the Word Document
        /// Printer trays on various HP printers change between models and Word documents 
        /// will not act the same when printed on different printers. This allows us
        /// to get the right code for the tray we want to print to.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="strTrayName">Name of the tray to search for, ie "Tray 1", "Tray 2", "Manual"</param>
        /// <param name="iDefaultBin">A default bin to return if not found ie. (int)WdPaperTray.wdPrinterUpperBin</param>
        /// <param name="wordDoc">A word document object that we want to check the printer for</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int GetBinNumber(string strTrayName, int iDefaultBin, Word.Document wordDoc)
        {
            //Code adapted from Microsoft KB article Q194789
            //HOWTO: Determine Available PaperBins with DeviceCapabilities API
            //Get the printer & port names and numbers of the current printer
            // 
            // Once we have the printer bin we can then use 
            // InvokeMember on the wordDoc.PageSetup object to set the bin.
            //
            // Example call to this method is 
            // int Tray1Code = GetBinNumber("Tray 1",(int)WdPaperTray.wdPrinterUpperBin);
            int BinRes;
            BinRes = iDefaultBin; //set up a default bin as the lower
            try
            {
                string sPort = wordDoc.Application.ActivePrinter.Substring(wordDoc.Application.ActivePrinter.IndexOf(" on ") + 3).Trim();
                string sCurrentPrinter = wordDoc.Application.ActivePrinter.Substring(0, wordDoc.Application.ActivePrinter.IndexOf(" on ")).Trim();
                //'Find out how many printer bins there are
                Int32 iBinCnt = DeviceCapabilities(sCurrentPrinter, sPort, DC_BINS, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (iBinCnt > -1)
                {
                    //'Set the array of bin numbers to the right size
                    UInt16[] iBinArray = new UInt16[iBinCnt];
                    //set up a buffer to receive the bin names - each name is up to 24 chars, null terminated
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[iBinCnt * 24];
                    // Load the array with the bin numbers
                    iBinCnt = DeviceCapabilitiesA(sCurrentPrinter, sPort, DC_BINS, iBinArray, IntPtr.Zero);
                    if (iBinCnt > -1)
                    {
                        // Load the array of bin names
                        iBinCnt = DeviceCapabilitiesA(sCurrentPrinter, sPort, DC_BINNAMES, buffer, IntPtr.Zero);
                        if (iBinCnt > -1)
                        {
                            string sBinNames = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            //split the null terminated strings into a string array for searching
                            while (sBinNames.IndexOf("\0\0") > -1) 
                            {
                                sBinNames = sBinNames.Replace("\0\0", "\0");
                            }
                            string[] arrBinNames = sBinNames.Split('\0');
                            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("prn nams = " + res );
                            int idx = 0;
                            foreach (string BinNam in arrBinNames)
                            {
                                if( BinNam.Trim().StartsWith(strTrayName))
                                {
                                    BinRes = iBinArray[idx];
                                    break;
                                }
                                idx++;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error - " + ex.Message );
            }
            return BinRes;
        }
```

Copied partly from the website due to restrictions, you can view the full code here:

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=3687&lngWId=10

Answer (score 2):

Check this code from MSDN. Have you tried it? May be you can match the PaperSize name with the tray name.

```
   // Add list of supported paper sizes found on the printer. 
    // The DisplayMember property is used to identify the property that will provide the display string.
    comboPaperSize.DisplayMember = "PaperName";

    PaperSize pkSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count; i++){
        pkSize = printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i];
        comboPaperSize.Items.Add(pkSize);
    }

    // Create a PaperSize and specify the custom paper size through the constructor and add to combobox.
    PaperSize pkCustomSize1 = new PaperSize("First custom size", 100, 200);

    comboPaperSize.Items.Add(pkCustomSize1);
```

Comment: Do you know what comboPaperSize actually is?

Answer (score 2):

I think an easier way in C# is to query the PrintDocument Printer Settings.

```
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
PrinterSettings printSettings = printDoc.PrinterSettings;

for (int i=0; i < printSettings.PaperSources.Count; i++)
{
    sTmp += printSettings.PaperSources[i].SourceName;
    sTmp += " : ";
    sTmp += printSettings.PaperSources[i].Kind.ToString();
    sTmp += " : ";
    sTmp += printSettings.PaperSources[i].RawKind.ToString();
    sTmp += "\n";
}

MessageBox.Show(sTmp, "Paper Sources for " + printSettings.PrinterName+ " : " + 
                    printSettings.IsDefaultPrinter.ToString());
```

If I look for "Tray 2" in SourceName and use RawKind, I get the  same answer as GetBinNumber above with having to import winspool.drv.

Am I missing something?